Detect and remove consecutive lines with the same information but with different amount of spaces in them
I posted a question about detect consecutive lines in a text, with the same words and the same order, the amount of spaces at leading, trailing, or between words may vary from one line to the other. The Ed Morton's answer was a good help. But now I want to remove those matched lines from the original file. So far I'm using a bash script with two awk commands, the first one comes from original post, to  do the job.
The bash script is delete_duplicated _lines.sh
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
awk '{currRec=$0; $1=$1; currKey=$0} prevKey==currKey{print prevRec ORS currRec ORS} {prevKey=currKey; prevRec=currRec}' $FILENAME > tmpfile.txt
awk 'FNR==NR && NF{lines[$0]; next} FNR!=NR && NF{if(!($0 in lines)) {print; print ""}}' tmpfile.txt $FILENAME

The original file myfile.txt is:
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

Mary has  a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
  Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

 Mary has a little lamb.  The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi
gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

 Elvis was the greatest singer of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.
Elvis was the greatest singer  of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn
fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
 Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi 

This has been the coldest winter in the last 20 years.
 This has  been the coldest winter in the  last 20 years.

When I apply the bash script ./delete_duplicated _lines.sh myfile.txt I get this output
 vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi

gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn

fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi 

That's exactly what I want.  But I'd like to do it with a regex so I could use with grep, sed or when parsing the text with an editor like sublime text without having to save the file fist.

Do you need to keep the excessive spaces? If not, then my idea is: "canonicalize" each line, so leading and trailing spaces are removed and consecutive spaces are compacted to a single space; the point is equivalent lines will become truly identical and you will be able to use uniq or whatever tool that works with identical lines.

There is no need to save a temporary file if you let the first awk invocation pipe into the second. You can then use sponge to save the result back to the original filename. This is not a real answer as I haven’t tested it, there might also be more efficient ways to do this which I haven’t really spent any time thinking about just yet.

This really isn't a job for regular expressions. What's worse, even if we do come up with one, it will not work in grep, or sed or sublime. Each of these tools uses different regex flavors, and none of them natively work with multi-line content as far as I know.

Regarding "I'd like to do it with a regex" - please bear in mind the quote:

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
regular expressions." Now they have two
problems.

We can help you do what you want in one awk (or perl, python, ruby, or similar) script, but trying to do what you want with a regexp would require an incomprehensible, unmaintainable nightmare even if it is possible.
Your pair of awk scripts isn't just deleting consecutive duplicate lines, by the way. If you get 2 consecutive lines of foo it'll delete them but then if you get a 3rd line of foo elsewhere in your input it'll delete THAT line too despite it not having a duplicate consecutive line. If you were going to use 2 scripts like that then the first one should print line numbers instead of line contents and then second one would skip line numbers that were present in the temp file, but you don't need to do any of that.
Below is how to do what you said you want to do, remove consecutive duplicate lines:

using any awk so it'll work on every Unix box without needing to install any other software, and
using a single call to awk so you don't need temp files or pipes or multiple passes of the input between scripts, and
only reading the input once so it'll work whether the input is
coming from a pipe or stored in a file, and
only storing 2 input lines at a time in memory so it'll work no matter how large the input is.

For example:
$ cat delete_duplicated_lines.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        prevRec = currRec
        prevKey = currKey
        currRec = $0
        $1 = $1        # Normalize "  foo    bar " to "foo bar"
        currKey = $0
        prtPrev()
    }
    END {
        prtPrev()
    }

    function prtPrev() {
        if ( prevKey == currKey ) {
            gotDup = 1
        }
        else {
            if ( (prevKey != "") && !gotDup ) {
                print prevRec ORS
            }
            gotDup = 0
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./delete_duplicated_lines.sh myfile.txt
vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi

gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn

fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi

Note that you don't need to use a temp file for this, and if you want to directly manipulate the output of some other tool you can do that, just replace cat myfile.txt below with whatever tool produces the output you're currently saving in myfile.txt:
$ cat myfile.txt | ./delete_duplicated_lines.sh
vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi

gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn

fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi


$ ./delete_duplicated_lines.sh < <(cat myfile.txt)
vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi

gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn

fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi


Per @EdMorton's suggestion, changed uniq -s to uniq -f and related adjustment.
An alternative using awk - uniq - awk command pipe which is a typical ETL task: using awk to prepare data, uniq to process data and then awk to merge data:
awk '{$1=$1; print NR,$0}' myfile.txt                  | \
  uniq -f1 -u                                          | \
  awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1+0];next}FNR in a' - myfile.txt

where

the first awk command rebuilds $0 so leading, trailing and redundant white spaces are removed, then we print the line number followed by $0
use uniq command to skip the first field and find uniq items, we need the line numbers here
the 2nd awk command then hash the line numbers from the above result and print the original lines based on the corresponding FNR.

this pipeline prints:
vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug



fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi
gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu


sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn
fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf


gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi 


"ETL".........?

@ilkkachu maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load?
